# Creating a setInterval on react using hooks with conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I need to create a poll request, but this need to be executed only when the user clicks on active button, and on every 5 seconds since the click,the request it will be made until the status is completed, I try to find solution here and the best solution was what I found is on this article https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/. I made an adaptation of it, but it's work as I want.

What I want is that setInterval only start to working at button clicks instead, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code

```
let times = 0;

export const request = id => {
  if (times === 5) {
    times = 0;
  } else {
    times++;
  }

  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (times === 5) {
        resolve({
          times,
          status: "completed"
        });
      } else {
        resolve({
          times,
          status: "in_progress"
        });
      }
    }, 2000)
  );
};

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  useInterval(async () => {
    if (!isActive) return;

    console.log("polling");
    const { status, times } = await request();
    console.log("times:", times);

    if (status === "completed") {
      setActive(false);
      console.log("completed");
    }
  }, 1000 * 5);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Poll testing</h1>
      <Button disabled={isActive} onClick={() => setActive(true)}>
        {isActive ? (
          <>
            <Spinner
              as="span"
              animation="border"
              size="sm"
              role="status"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          "Active"
        )}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can run this code on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-poll-hook-jxccy

Comment: This already starts at button click, do you want it to pause every 5 seconds and wait for the “continue” button click?

Comment: No it's not, the code is running setInterval on background. But the request is only made on isActive true. But I don't want the setInterval runs at same time of the click. The button needs be disabled until the request is completed.

Comment: “But I don't want the setInterval runs at same time of the click”, so you want it to run always? And when requesting, just.. follow it?

Comment: Hello, @leverglowh, This useInterval function create a clock of 5 seconds, this functions is ticking on background, this because I need to check here `if (!isActive) return;` Once, this is active, on the next tick, it'll make a request. But I did not want to wait the next tick, I wanted one way to start to execute `useInterval` when `isActive` is true.

Answer (score 0):

The `if (delay !== null)` check in the `useInterval` hook is intended exactly for this purpose.

Remove the `isActive` check from the body of the callback and use it instead to conditionally pass `null` for the delay:

```js
useInterval(async () => {
  console.log("polling");
  const { status, times } = await request();
  console.log("times:", times);

  if (status === "completed") {
    setActive(false);
    console.log("completed");
  }
}, isActive ? 1000 * 5 : null);
```